# iOS: XML validation with an XSD

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, xsd, xsd-validation

I would like to validate some **xml** with an **xsd** on the iOS platform. I have done some searches and not found anything. Anyone have any code i can use to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic XML Schema validation is expensive, did you consider compiling the XSD into code using a tool like CodeSynthesis?