# NSXMLParser and validation against a DTD on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios

I have to use `NSXMLParser` to parse a XML file, but I need to validate it against a DTD. What is the best practice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your DTD to an XML Schema then generate code which enforces the validation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510126/free-dtd-to-xsd-conversion-utility) and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642608/ios-xml-validation-with-an-xsd/4695346#4695346) question.

Edit: Added DTD-to-XSD link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate since the linked question is about XML Schema and not DTD. So without further explanations, your link-only answer is not very helpful. And if it *was* a duplicate, I think the link should be posted as a comment an not as an answer.

Comment: Happy now? I think this answer is very helpful.